# Sort Column Data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need a command to sort the column `Document`'s data with this JavaScript function. I've tried `"asSorting":["asc"]` as shown below and it isn't working,  and `"bSort":"asc"` and others aren't working either. I'm not sure what the command would be to sort it.

```javascript
SomeAdapter.method('getHeaders', function() {
return [
        { "sTitle": "ID" ,"bVisible":false},
        { "sTitle": "Document", "asSorting":["asc"]},
        { "sTitle": "Upload Date"}
    ];
});
```

Comment: Is this in some framework?

Comment: I don't see any columns. Is that code running in the browser? What framework are you using there? And what do you want to sort in which way?